# Printing 2D text using lwjgl

Tags: 2d, lwjgl

I am trying to make a simple opengl game window with some text on it using lwjgl. But have ran into problems, and have spent the last day researching on google what the problem might be - but have a look at my code.

Main class:
    public class Test implements Runnable {

```
// The window handle
private long window;
private boolean running;
private Thread thread;
FontUtils font = null;

private int WIDTH = 600;
private int HEIGHT = 300;

public Test(){
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Game");

    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
    init();
    try {
        font = new FontUtils("src/test/Calibri.ttf", 300);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double delta = 0.0;
    double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    while (running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if (delta >= 1.0){
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println(updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
            running = false;
        }
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();    
}

private void update(){
    glfwPollEvents(); 
}

private void init() {

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if (!glfwInit())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");


    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Test", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    // Center our window
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2, (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwShowWindow(window);

    GL.createCapabilities();

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);        
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);                    

    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);                
    GL11.glClearDepth(1);                                       

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GL11.glViewport(0,0, WIDTH ,HEIGHT);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
}

private void render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
    font.drawText("Hello this", 300, 400);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}
```

FontUtils:

```
public class FontUtils {
//Constants
private final Map<Integer,String> CHARS = new HashMap<Integer,String>() {{
    put(0, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    put(1, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    put(2, "0123456789");
    put(3, "ÄÖÜäöüß");
    put(4, " $+-*/=%\"'#@&_(),.;:?!\\|<>[]§`^~");
}};

//Variables
private java.awt.Font font;
private FontMetrics fontMetrics;
private BufferedImage bufferedImage;
private int fontTextureId;

//Getters
public float getFontImageWidth() {
    return (float) CHARS.values().stream().mapToDouble(e -> fontMetrics.getStringBounds(e, null).getWidth()).max().getAsDouble();
}
public float getFontImageHeight() {
    return (float) CHARS.keySet().size() * (this.getCharHeight());
}
public float getCharX(char c) {
    String originStr = CHARS.values().stream().filter(e -> e.contains("" + c)).findFirst().orElse("" + c);
    return (float) fontMetrics.getStringBounds(originStr.substring(0, originStr.indexOf(c)), null).getWidth();
}
public float getCharY(char c) {
    float lineId = (float) CHARS.keySet().stream().filter(i -> CHARS.get(i).contains("" + c)).findFirst().orElse(0);
    return this.getCharHeight() * lineId;
}
public float getCharWidth(char c) {
    return fontMetrics.charWidth(c);
}
public float getCharHeight() {
    return (float) (fontMetrics.getMaxAscent() + fontMetrics.getMaxDescent());
}

//Constructors
public FontUtils(String path, float size) throws Exception {
    font = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(path)).deriveFont(size);

    //Generate buffered image
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    Graphics2D graphics = gc.createCompatibleImage(1, 1, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT).createGraphics();
    graphics.setFont(font);

    fontMetrics = graphics.getFontMetrics();
    bufferedImage = graphics.getDeviceConfiguration().createCompatibleImage((int) getFontImageWidth(),(int) getFontImageHeight(),Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);

    //Generate texture
    fontTextureId = glGenTextures();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTextureId);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,(int) getFontImageWidth(),(int) getFontImageHeight(),0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, asByteBuffer());

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}

//Functions
public void drawText(String text, int x, int y) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this.fontTextureId);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    int xTmp = x;
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        float width = getCharWidth(c);
        float height = getCharHeight();
        float cw = 1f / getFontImageWidth() * width;
        float ch = 1f / getFontImageHeight() * height;
        float cx = 1f / getFontImageWidth() * getCharX(c);
        float cy = 1f / getFontImageHeight() * getCharY(c);

        glTexCoord2f(cx, cy);
        glVertex3f(xTmp, y, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(cx + cw, cy);
        glVertex3f(xTmp + width, y, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(cx + cw, cy + ch);
        glVertex3f(xTmp + width, y + height, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(cx, cy + ch);
        glVertex3f(xTmp, y + height, 0);

        xTmp += width;
    }

    glEnd();
}

//Conversions
public ByteBuffer asByteBuffer() {

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer;

    //Draw the characters on our image
    Graphics2D imageGraphics = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();
    imageGraphics.setFont(font);
    imageGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
    imageGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    // draw every CHAR by line...
    imageGraphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    CHARS.keySet().stream().forEach(i -> imageGraphics.drawString(CHARS.get(i), 0, fontMetrics.getMaxAscent() + (this.getCharHeight() * i)));

    //Generate texture data
    int[] pixels = new int[bufferedImage.getWidth() * bufferedImage.getHeight()];
    bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth(), bufferedImage.getHeight(), pixels, 0, bufferedImage.getWidth());
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((bufferedImage.getWidth() * bufferedImage.getHeight() * 4));

    for (int y = 0; y < bufferedImage.getHeight(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bufferedImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            int pixel = pixels[y * bufferedImage.getWidth() + x];
            byteBuffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));   // Red component
            byteBuffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));    // Green component
            byteBuffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));           // Blue component
            byteBuffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));   // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
        }
    }

    byteBuffer.flip();

    return byteBuffer;
}
```

Comment: What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: No text is getting printed, and I don't get any error messages